# How to call a method from another class that do not necessarily exist ? In java by the way

Tags: java, methods, polymorphism

I know the question is not really clear so I explain.
If I made a piece of code I want somebody to be able to add functionnalities to it. So I want that my core code verify if the extended code exist or not and call a method in this extended code only if this code exist (the extended one). And I want this in every extended code maybe made by different people.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: In Java you can do this with `Class.forname(String name)`.

Comment: I don't know Java, but regarding your question, it is about [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)). Just google it out, there are plenty of tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Nice clue, so I read some doc about it. But I didn't find a way to load a class if I don't know the name of the class. If my program want to load severals extensions, each extension can't have a class with the same name (including package path) so how to load something like a MainExtensionLoader in every extension using reflection ? But this is a nice feature I didn't know.

Thanks for reading.